# What is the best way to render a large table to the mobile devices?

Tags: html, angularjs, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

for my web application using AngularJs and Bootstrap as a web framework.

I'm implementing a table for insertion of working hours, overtime, travel expenses, repayments etc ..

The table is currently composed of 6 columns collapsible in 5.

Here are two screenshots with the desktop version:

[image]

[image]

These however are 2 screenshots mobile version on Nexus 5:

[image]
[image]

The visualization on the mobile version is clearly very bad. Plus it must consider that the user, in this version, should scroll sideways on each line. Which makes the application a non-friendly application.
The question is: How to make a table of this type in such a way that in both versions, the visualization is clear, clean and friendly?